# ZPL center variable text

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I just modified a label for an Zebra printer.
I almost finished it, but I am currently stuck on 1 row, i have read different topics on multiple sites but nothing help me to get what I want.
Our label is 10cm height and 15cm width, the row below needs to center automatically from the middle to the side.

```
^CF0,10^FO45,005^FB900,1,0,C^FH\^FD$$$WAVENAME$$$^FS
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Regards Martijn,

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the text width an set the ^FO parameters accordingly.
Alternativly you can use the `^FB` command to center text, like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50498811/11329562).